# Evaluating Knuth's arrow notation in a function

Tags: c#, function, math, knuth

I am having trouble calculating **Knuth's arrow notation**, which is ↑ and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), within a function. What I've made so far is:

```
int arrowCount = (int)arrowNum.Value; // Part of
BigInteger a = (int)aNum.Value;       // the input I
BigInteger b = (int)bNum.Value;       // already have
BigInteger result = a;
BigInteger temp = a;
for(int i = 0; i < arrowCount; i++)
{
    result = Power(temp, b);
    temp = r;
    b = a;
}
```

with power being

```
BigInteger Power(BigInteger Base, BigInteger Pow)
    {
        BigInteger x = Base;
        for(int i = 0; i < (Pow-1); i++)
        {
            x *= Base;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

but it's incorrect with it's values and I can't figure out a way to fix it. It can handle 1 arrow problems like **3↑3** (which is **3^3** = **9**), but it can't handle any more arrows than that.

I need a way to **figure out more arrows**, such as **3↑↑3**,

which should be ***7625597484987 (3^27)*** and I get ***19683 (27^3)***. If you could help me to figure how I could get the proper output and explain what it is I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You know what'd be nice? Knowing why people downvote your stuff.

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Comment: That is the very link I mentioned in my post. I understood it, but I can't seem to create a function that implements such a thing.

Comment: You have to figure out 1 arrow, 2 arrows case, and use loop or recursive function for 3 arrows or more case.

Comment: I said I figured out 1 arrow case in my post, and that I _couldn't_ figure out 2 arrows case. It's the whole reason I asked this :P

Comment: In 2 arrows case, you have loop `b-1` times `temp = power(a, temp)` and `temp` start with `a` before the loop.

Comment: Okay, but _where_ do I loop `b` times?

Comment: After you complete your code, please show me how do you do in case 3 arrows or more :D.

Comment: If I knew how to complete it, I wouldn't ask this question :P. But where do you think I should loop `b` times, or how do you think I should actually complete it?

Comment: It is not hard, right? :D I posted in answer, i used java and double but it not the problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote it in java, and use double for input parameter:

```
    private static double knuthArrowMath(double a, double b, int arrowNum)
{
    if( arrowNum == 1)
        return Math.pow(a, b);
    double result = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < b - 1; i++)
    {
        result = knuthArrowMath(a, result, arrowNum - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly :D, I just had to change some doubles to BigIntegers, a power function, and maybe see if I can make it faster :D

Comment: You have to rewrite your power function too, `Power(a, 0) ` equals 1, your function return `a`.

Comment: Yeah, but the input section strictly prohibits anything less than 1, so I think I'm good. Thanks for reminding me of that though :P

Answer (score 1):

If you expect 7625597484987 (3^**27**) but get 19683 (**27**^3), isn't it then a simple matter of swapping the arguments when calling your power function?

Looking at your Power function your code snippet seems to call Power with **temp** as base and **b** as power:

```
int arrowCount = (int)arrowNum.Value; // Part of
BigInteger a = (int)aNum.Value;       // the input I
BigInteger b = (int)bNum.Value;       // already have
BigInteger result = a;
BigInteger temp = a;
for(int i = 0; i < arrowCount; i++)
{
    result = Power(temp, b);
    temp = result;
    b = a;
}
```

Shouldn't temp an b be swapped so you get `result = Power(b, temp)` to get the desired result?

So pass 1 results calls `Power(3, 3)` resulting in `temp = 27` and pass 2 calls `Power(3, 27)`. The reason it only works for single arrow now is because swapping arguments for the first `Power(base, power)` call doesn't matter.

As you point out in your answer this doesn't cover all situations. Given the examples you provided I created this little console application:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Arrow(3, 3));
            Console.WriteLine(Arrow(4, 4, 1));
            Console.WriteLine(Arrow(3, 4, 1));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static BigInteger Arrow(BigInteger baseNumber, BigInteger arrows)
        {
            return Arrow(baseNumber, baseNumber, arrows-1);
        }

        private static int Arrow(BigInteger baseNumber, BigInteger currentPower, BigInteger arrows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1}", baseNumber, currentPower);
            var result = Power(baseNumber, currentPower);

            if (arrows == 1)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Arrow(baseNumber, result, arrows - 1);
            }
        }

        private static BigInteger Power(BigInteger number, BigInteger power)
        {
            int x = number;
            for (int i = 0; i < (power - 1); i++)
            {
                x *= number;
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but although this does give me the proper answer for 3↑↑3, 4↑↑2 (Which is 4^4 = 256) gives me 65536 (4^8) instead. Swapping these 2 values also causes 3↑4 (3^4 = 81) to evaluate to 4↑3 (4^3 = 64).

Comment: Ah I see, I updated my answer to accommodate your other examples as well. I rewrote a little console application to cover this since your original snippet was a bit hard to read imo.

Comment: Thank you, I'll experiment with what you made to get the proper values I need.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to use the `BigInteger.Pow()` function.
It might look a little odd, but that is because the C# `BigInterger.Pow(x, y)` only accepts an int for y, and teterations have HUGE exponents.  I had to "flip the script" and convert x^y = y^x for this specific case.
I didn't add in any error checking, and it expects all numbers to be positive ints.

I **know** this works for x^^2 and x^^3.  I also know it works for 2^^4 and 2^^5.  I don't have the computing power/memory/math knowledge to know if it works for any other numbers.  2^^4 and 2^^5 were the only ones I could check and test.  It *may* work for other numbers but I was not able to confirm that.

```
int baseNum = 4;
int exp = 3;
// this example is 4^^3
BigInteger bigAnswer = tetration(baseNum, exp);

// Here is what the method that "does the work" looks like.  

    // This looks a little odd but that is because I am using BigInteger.Pow(x,y)
    // Unfortunately, y can only be an int.  Tetrations have huge exponents, so I had to figure out a
    // way to have x^y work as y^x for this specific application
    // no error checking in here, and it expects positive ints only
    // I *know* this works for x^^2, x^^3, but I don't know if it works for
    // any other number than 2 at ^^4 or higher
    public static BigInteger tetration(int baseNum, int exp)
    {
        if (exp > 2)
        {
            exp = (int)Math.Pow(baseNum, (exp - 3));
        }
        else
        {
            exp = exp - 2;
        }

        Func<BigInteger, int, BigInteger> bigPowHelper = (x, y) => BigInteger.Pow(x, y);
        BigInteger bigAnswer = baseNum;

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(baseNum, exp); i++)
        {
            bigAnswer = bigPowHelper(bigAnswer, baseNum);
        }
        return bigAnswer;
    }
```